# Is serverfault.com becoming slower?

Tags: discussion

I swear that for the past couple of weeks or so the speed of responses on serverfault.com has really degraded from what it used to be.  Is it time to beef that site up a little?

Comment: Seems fine to me. To be clear: You're talking about the time it takes for HTTP requests to complete, not the turnaround time from question to answer -- right? :)

Comment: @voretaq7 I think he's referring to answer times.

Comment: @Jacob, that's what I thought, but then 'beef that site up' sounds like he's asking about the hardware.

Comment: If the OP is indeed talking about answer response time, perhaps it's because on an increase in the incompleteness or ambiguity in questions lately...

Comment: @Jacob That was my initial impression as well, but the question in that context makes no sense: The universal solution to slow answer times is "hire the talent" and a lecture about not complaining about free services :-)

Comment: I've noticed a couple of intermittent packet loss issues which [apparently are due to the upstream ISP's (peer1.net) problems](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3396392#3396392). The last days seemed to be fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's nothing at your end? I've noticed no difference here.

Comment: Interesting other SE sites seem a lot more responsive, even the meta site.

Comment: I can middle-click a question and it's fully loaded and ready to go before I can navigate to the tab that it opened in. Seems fine to me.

Comment: @mdpc I can't see a difference here. You've not been [slow banned](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html) have you? :)

Comment: @mdpc, I'm not seeing any difference between meta and main.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you located?

I'm in Sydney, Australia and for the last 10 months I've had speed issues with the site - it's so "normal" now that I don't even notice them.

See my [meta.stackoverflow question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92452/cdn-sstatic-net-is-slowing-down-initial-page-loads) - there's a lot of info on how to diagnose CDN issues in the answers.

Comment: I used to see that sstatic domain issue, but haven't seen it in six months or so.